# wordpress docker exits immediately

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I’m trying to get wordpress up and running with docker on OSX 10.12.1...

First I start up mysql:

```
docker run --name dockermysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress -e MYSQL_USER=wordpress -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql:5
```

That seems to work fine:

```
$ docker ps -a
f7d1562def4a        mysql:5             "docker-entrypoint.sh"   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes              3306/tcp            dockermysql
```

but then I try wordpress…

```
docker run --name dockerpress --link dockermysql:mysql -d wordpress --net="host" -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

and it seems like it exits immediately

```
$ docker ps -a
84cc4d2abb57       wordpress        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   7 minutes ago        Exited (2) 7 minutes ago                       dockerpress
f7d1562def4a        mysql:5             "docker-entrypoint.sh"   33 minutes ago      Up 33 minutes              3306/tcp            dockermysql
```

Here are the results of `docker inspect dockerpress`:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "84cc4d2abb57d00fbd67d10c02cc6333a401a7d8bfe4bc15f588da11a834333f",
        "Created": "2016-11-28T14:41:04.757044577Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "--net=host",
            "-e",
            "WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress",
            "-e",
            "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=secret"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 2,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-11-28T14:41:05.523186975Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2016-11-28T14:41:05.619181506Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:ee397259d4e59c65e2c1c5979a3634eb3ab106bba389acea8b21862053359134",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/84cc4d2abb57d00fbd67d10c02cc6333a401a7d8bfe4bc15f588da11a834333f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/84cc4d2abb57d00fbd67d10c02cc6333a401a7d8bfe4bc15f588da11a834333f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/84cc4d2abb57d00fbd67d10c02cc6333a401a7d8bfe4bc15f588da11a834333f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/84cc4d2abb57d00fbd67d10c02cc6333a401a7d8bfe4bc15f588da11a834333f/84cc4d2abb57d00fbd67d10c02cc6333a401a7d8bfe4bc15f588da11a834333f-json.log",
        "Name": "/dockerpress",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": [
                "/dockermysql:/dockerpress/mysql"
            ],
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "928da9b62b2adb3dd93905dfd702b766d80f0e7bb6f17b7e7f57f7c6433bdc5d",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/928da9b62b2adb3dd93905dfd702b766d80f0e7bb6f17b7e7f57f7c6433bdc5d/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/www/html",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "84cc4d2abb57",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
                "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
                "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2",
                "GPG_KEYS=0BD78B5F97500D450838F95DFE857D9A90D90EC1 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3",
                "PHP_VERSION=5.6.28",
                "PHP_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.28.tar.xz/from/this/mirror",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.28.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror",
                "PHP_SHA256=07187ba2870f89cef334cd2ad6cb801aeec5eaf283da0293a9a6be75d6786d11",
                "PHP_MD5=1e01c66b2e67ab3b56a6180ee560fe4c",
                "WORDPRESS_VERSION=4.6.1",
                "WORDPRESS_SHA1=027e065d30a64720624a7404a1820e6c6fff1202"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "--net=host",
                "-e",
                "WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress",
                "-e",
                "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=secret"
            ],
            "Image": "wordpress",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/www/html": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "d946a78e9a50fc8fb10873a0c043c9f49a377db44b19edb5e83362b37c025948",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": null,
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/d946a78e9a50",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "37e08b5c5d5f8a159552b8ab22a0fb37bfbcfd720fd83ce20a983ab85e60157f",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: it seems to me that in a `docker run` you need to have all the options before the image name. You do it for mysql, but not for wordpress. Can you try `docker run --name dockerpress --link dockermysql:mysql --net="host" -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=secret  -d wordpress`

Comment: @user2915097Thanks. that doesn't seem to make much of a difference, though. Wordpress starts just fine but exits almost immediately and there are a lot of blank values when I inspect (for instance there's no networking info)

Comment: can you launch it with adding at the end `;docker logs $(docker ps -lq)` this should show a few things

Comment: @user2915097ah! It looks like the issue is with permissions on the mysql container because I'm not using the same credentials. Thanks :)
I was trying to check logs before with `docker logs dockerpress` after it finished running but I was getting an error so that's a nice trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still learning, like me, I found the better solution here was to use docker-compose as described in the docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

One nice thing about this, aside from the fact that it's way easier to deal with, is you can see all of your env variables to avoid mismatched variables between your db and wp server - which is what was causing my initial problem

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to pull image version 5.7 for mysql and wordpress the latest image version.

Manual who i created it:

```
---1. docker pull wordpress 
---2. docker pull mysql:5.7 
---3. docker run --name nwplm-database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd -d mysql:5.7 
---4. docker run --name nwplm-wordpress --link nwplm-database -p 8080:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=nwplm-database:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=nwplm-wordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_ -d wordpress 
---5. open localhost:8080 in your browser
```

Comment: manual who i created it:
---1. docker pull wordpress ---2. docker pull mysql:5.7 ----3. docker run --name nwplm-database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd -d mysql:5.7 ---4. docker run --name nwplm-wordpress --link nwplm-database -p 8080:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=nwplm-database:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=Pa$$w0rd -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=nwplm-wordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_  -d wordpress ---5. open localhost:8080 in your browser

Comment: I think it's easier to read your answer when you edit your message rather than posting it in a comment...